# Multi-monitors and the corners of the screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse

I currently have two monitors (let's call them "left" and "middle" - you'll see why in a sec), and would love three (let's call it "right").  However, I often will throw the mouse-cursor up to the top-right corner on "middle" because for a maximised window that's where the close button will be.

If I add the "right" monitor, the mouse cursor will just carry on off "middle" into "right", and aiming for the close button on "middle" will become more difficult.

I'm currently using UltraMon 3.10, but does anyone know of a way to get the mouse to stick to the corners, so that it doesn't go off into the other monitor ([Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) allows this by configuring the "gap" where the mouse is allowed to travel from monitor to monitor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the accepted answer:

As of Windows 8,  you don't need to make the adjustment in resolution settings anymore. Even with a "right" monitor that extends up to the top of the one to the left of it (or even higher), Windows now provides a [six pixel boundary](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors/) at the very top and bottom of the screen - a region that the mouse is never allowed to cross until you move it away a little.

Answer (score 16):

You could use Windows built in tools. On the resolution settings screen, drag the "middle" monitor down slightly in the layout section at the top, so that hitting the top right corner of the middle monitor will cause it to hit an invisible boundary.

Then you'll just need to ensure you hit the top of the screen before going to the right of the screen.

I've done it for mine, and it's worked for me :)

Comment: I'd just like to say that this is brilliant solution! :) You get my vote.

Comment: Do you mean "drag UP"? That's what works for me.

Comment: This is unbelievable, I spent 10 hours to fix this :)

Answer (score 5):

Despite it's limited sounding name, [Dual Display Mouse Manager](http://ddmm.sourceforge.net/) may be exactly what you're looking for.  I tried using it for a while but just never quite got used to it.  I like to sling my mouse around quickly, so I'd drag a window across monitors and let go of the mouse button only to have it snap back because the software wanted to "pause" my pointer.  Maybe it needs to take pointer velocity into account.

Comment: Since I didn't clarify: DDMM will work with 3 monitors, which is why I used the phrase "limited sounding" in reference to the name.

Comment: Great program!  This functionality should be built into every modern operating system.