# incorrect alignment when using multiple monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

Monitor 1: Philips PHL 246e9q (1920x1080)

Monitor 2: AOC 2369 (1920x1080)

As you can see in the picture, Bottom VLC window's alignment is way off. This is not a scale or resolution issue.

How can I fix this?

[image]

screenshot of the same scene

[image: screenshot of the same scene]

[image: screenshot of the Windows display settings page]

Comment: In addition the the photo, please provide a screenshot of the same scene. Also, please provide a screenshot of the Windows display settings page. Are you using any multiscreen customization software (like Ultramon)?

Comment: @DanielB added. No, I'm not using a customization software.

Comment: Looks like you got it already, just as feedback: The screenshot of Display settings isn’t useful because only one display was connected/active when it was taken. I would have expected what’s in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is unbelievable! By default display arrange was like this
[image]

Then I saw this answer https://superuser.com/a/136391/510639 and changed it to this. I've always thought that setting was for just numbering monitors :)

[image]